# When a sentence starts with Simple present tense should I end with past/simple present tense?

Tags: tenses

In this sentence

> Reports net profit of Rs5.16 crore for the financial year ended Mar 2019.

Since  the sentence starts with 'Reports' - simple present tense, should I end the sentence with 'ending Mar 2019' instead of 'ended Mar 2019' to be in sync with the tense?

Comment: Are you missing a subject or are the reports really netting a profit?

Comment: I assume that by *crore* you mean *for*?

Comment: @JasonBassford, "crore" means ten million (like "dozen" means 12).

Comment: The "below sentence" really isn't a sentence.  It lacks a subject.

Comment: Especially within the less precise demands for grammaticality a non-sentence such as your example makes, either 'the financial year ending Mar 2019' or 'the financial year ended Mar 2019' are totally acceptable. Both are commonly used (but the 'ended' version could normally only be/have been used sensibly post March 2019).

Comment: *Reports* and *ended* have nothing to do with each other. *Ended* modifies "financial year" and is correctly in the past tense. Relax!

Answer (score -1):

In your example sentence, Jags, the simple answer would be to use the past tense at the end, and simple present at the beginning.

In general, financial statements follow this format:

Entity
Type of Statement
Period or date

E.g,

National General, Inc.
Income Statement
For the Year Ended December 31, 1877

Mega Micro Association, PLC
Balance Sheet
December 31, 2018

Blue Sky Adventures, LLC
Projected Costs of Operations
For the Period Begun February 1, 2019, and Ending September 30, 2144

Usually one would say that George or Perdue Pharmaceuticals reports ... .

Newspaper Headlines, etc., don't necessarily follow established usage, sometimes with a funny effect.

Oh, and I understand a crore is, in scientific notation 10 ^ 7.